# Remove all instances where a string occurs between two other strings with bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that edits a json file to strip out entire objects, but I have hit a wall.

here is sample data

```
[
   {
      "MapObject" : {
         "BoundingBox" : [ -1313.574, -1010.804, -1113.574, -810.804 ],
         "Caption" : "Ref46",
         "Comment" : "",
         "Position" : {
            "CPosition" : [ -1213.574, -910.804, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Size" : {
            "CPosition" : [ 100, 100, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Type" : "moReferencePointID"
      }
   },
   {
      "MapObject" : {
         "BoundingBox" : [ -1313.06, 495.39, -1113.06, 695.39 ],
         "Caption" : "Ref47",
         "Comment" : "",
         "Position" : {
            "CPosition" : [ -1213.06, 595.39, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Size" : {
            "CPosition" : [ 100, 100, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Type" : "moReferencePointID"
      }
   },
  {
      "MapObject" : {
         "BoundingBox" : [ -18070, 1180, -17870, 1380 ],
         "Caption" : "Path way84",
         "Comment" : "",
         "ExecutableMapObject" : {
            "BehaviourList" : [
               {
                  "Speed" : 200,
                  "Type" : "bcSpeed"
               },
               {
                  "AvoidanceSpeed" : 150,
                  "FailureAction" : 0,
                  "FailureRetries" : 60,
                  "FailureWait" : 10,
                  "PathMode" : 2,
                  "PerSegment" : 15,
                  "ReturnToStart" : 0,
                  "ScanAngle" : 0.06981317007977778,
                  "Type" : "bcObstacleAvoidance",
                  "Wait" : 10,
                  "WaitUnits" : 2
               },
               {
                  "BinarySensorStates" : 3,
                  "SensorSensitivityList" : [
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 65536,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 70,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 70
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 131072,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 70,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 70
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 262144,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 240,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 240
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 524288,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 240,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 240
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 1048576,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 240,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 240
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 2097152,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 280,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 280
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 4194304,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 320,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : true,
                        "StopDistance" : 320
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 8388608,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 0,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : false,
                        "StopDistance" : 0
                     },
                     {
                        "IgnoreMapData" : false,
                        "Mask" : 16777216,
                        "SpeedCapDistance" : 0,
                        "SpeedCapEnabled" : false,
                        "StopDistance" : 0
                     }
                  ],
                  "SpeedCap" : 30,
                  "Type" : "bcObstacleSensitivity2"
               }
            ],
            "EntryPoint" : {
               "CPosition" : [ -13450, 1290, 0, 0 ]
            },
            "ExitPoint" : {
               "CPosition" : [ -17970, 1280, 0, 0 ]
            },
            "RelocateOnExecute" : false,
            "Required" : false,
            "TwoWay" : false
         },
         "GoalSet" : [
            {
               "Path" : {
                  "PathType" : "pitLinear",
                  "Segments" : [
                     {
                        "Segment" : [ -13450, 1290, -17970, 1280 ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "Position" : {
            "CPosition" : [ -17970, 1280, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Size" : {
            "CPosition" : [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Type" : "moLinePathID"
      }
   },
   {
      "MapObject" : {
         "AttributeList" : [
            [ "Lock", "{} LabInt {}" ]
         ],
         "BoundingBox" : [ -12350, -500, -12150, -300 ],
         "Caption" : "QUEUE/LabInt",
         "Comment" : "",
         "ExecutableMapObject" : {
            "EntryPoint" : {
               "CPosition" : [ -12250, -400, 0, 0 ]
            },
            "ExitPoint" : {
               "CPosition" : [ -12250, -400, 0, 0 ]
            },
            "RelocateOnExecute" : false,
            "Required" : false,
            "TwoWay" : false
         },
         "Position" : {
            "CPosition" : [ -12250, -400, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Size" : {
            "CPosition" : [ 100, 100, 0, 0 ]
         },
         "Type" : "moHotPointID"
      }
   },
]
```

Each object begins with

```
    {
```

and ends with

```
    },
```

I want to remove all objects and their data that contain "Type" : "moReferencePointID" and "moReferenceLineID".

There are multiple instances of Type in some objects.

I've been monkeying with sed and awk using what I can find online and can't quite get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

I'd post what I've done so far, but it definitely won't work...

Comment: That isn't a bash script....

Comment: Neither is awk or sed...

Comment: true... I thought you were making a comment about using a separate program that could not be integrated into a script to parse and remove json objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex is the wrong answer for parsing structured text**; using a parser is the right answer. Reading the whole file into memory is the wrong answer, too, but that's what parsers do, so meh.

That said, the wrong answer is sometimes okay for:

- throwaway scripts on trivial, non-production datasets where you have absolute control over the input. For example, as a one-shot command to migrate a small amount of data between two systems, where you don't want to go writing a script for it.
- where all you have is a text editor.
- where you are on a live server and don't want to install or write additional utilities for a trivial one-off task.
- where you are working on a readonly server and can't write scripts
- various disaster recovery/mitigation situations.

It's important to know when not to use regexes, and how to use the more powerful and reliable alternatives: but when you really need them, knowing how to kludge a task with a regex can be a lifesaver.

At the very least, this is an interesting pedagogical exercise for exploring regular expressions and multiline-text-block handling with various unix command line utilities.

---

**PHP:**

```bash
php -r '$a=file_get_contents("data.json");file_put_contents("cleaned.json", preg_replace("/\{\s*\"MapObject(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+\"Type\"\s*:\s*\"moReference(?:Point|Line)ID\"(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+},?\s*/", "", $a));'
```

**Perl:**

The `$_=do{local $/;<>};` just makes it read the file in as one line.

```bash
perl -e '$_=do{local $/;<>};$_=~s/\{\s*\"MapObject(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+\"Type\"\s*:\s*\"moReference(?:Point|Line)ID\"(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+},?\s*//g;open($fh,">","cleaned.json");print $fh $_;' data.json
```

**Awk:**

The `RS="<{EOF}>"` just makes it read the file in as one line. Replace the string with any string that definitely won't appear in your dataset.

```bash
awk -v RS="<{EOF}>" '{gsub(/\{[\r\n\t ]*\"MapObject/, "\x1E&");print $0}' < data.json > data1.json
awk -v RS="<{EOF}>" '{gsub(/\x1E[^\x1E]*\"Type\"[\t ]*:[\t ]*\"moReference(Point|Line)ID\"[^\x1E]*},[\r\n\t ]*|\x1E/, "");print $0}' < data1.json > cleaned.json
```

**Sed:**

The `-e 1h;2,$H;$!d;g` just makes it read the file in as one line.

```bash
 sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -E -e 's/\{\s*\"MapObject/\x1E\0/g' < data.json > data2.json
 sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -E -e 's/\x1E|\{[^\x1E]*\"Type\"\s*:\s*\"moReference(Point|Line)ID\"[^\x1E]*},\s*//g' < data2.json > cleaned.json
```

**OSX Sed**

```
echo 'Just use vi' | sed -e '' && vi data.json
```

---

In all cases above, I've done whatever it took to read the whole file in as a single string, then globally replaced what's matched by the regex with an empty string.

These solutions rely on the fact that each object begins with an identifiable opening pattern `\{\s*"MapObject"\s*:\s*\{`, which appears exactly once, at the beginning of each object.

PHP and Perl could just use this directly, using negative lookahead assertions.

However, Sed and Awk don't support look-around assertions, nor non-greedy matching. So there, I needed a single-width marker, so I had to do it in multiple passes: one to append some marker characters to the opening pattern (I picked 0x1E, ascii control code for "Record Separator"); and one to do the actual replacement.

If your code might contain arbitrary byte values, rather than readable text, then you will need another two passes, to first replace all 0x1E with a string that doesn't appear in your text, then replace that string back at the end.

Awk also don't seem to support (on my OSX machine) the \s escape for whitespace, so I've used character groups instead.

The regex can be described as:

```regex
\{\s*"MapObject"          The opening pattern, starting an object.
(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+  Some characters, not the opening pattern.
\"Type\"                  Literal quoted string "Type".
\s*:\s*                   Whitespace wrapped literal colon ':'.
\"moReference             Literal doublequote and start of string.
(?:                       Non-capturing group of...
  Point                   ...literal string 'Point'...
  |                       ...or...
  Line                    ...literal string 'Line'.
)                         Finish that logical grouping.
ID\"                      End of literal string and doublequote.
(?:(?!MapObject)[\s\S])+  More characters, not the opening pattern.
}                         Closing brace.
,?                        Optional comma.
\s*                       Optional trailing whitespace.
```

You can see this terrible beast in action here, where it can be seen working with an object containing multiple Type lines: https://regex101.com/r/XGULr5/4

Comment: You are right with #1 the { and } do appear in the BLAH parts. I will update with actual data.

Comment: Ok, I will try in the morning when I get to work. The reason I am so set on "simple" bash is that this has to work in the field on installers laptops running Ubuntu 14.04. I am limited to what is in our generic image.

Comment: @KipK I've updated it with working versions for Perl, Awk and Sed, and deleted all the old stuff from this answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sory for the delayed response. I did try converting it to sed, and that didn't work well...

Comment: I used both your awk and sed ones, and they work beautifully. Thank you very much! There is a lot here that I need to pick over and learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is your friend in this situation. The cookbook for it [has an example](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key) that should be adaptable to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
if ($0 ~ /{/) {
    strt=1;cnt++
    }
if (strt=1) {
            print cnt
            bits[cnt]=bits[cnt]"\n"$0
            if ( $0 ~ /Type/ ) {
                                    typ[cnt]=$0
            }
        }
if ( $0 ~ /}/ ) {
    strt=0
    }
}
END{
for ( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) {
    if ( typ[i] ~ /NotGood/ || typ[i] ~ /Bad/ ) {

    }
else {
    printf bits[i]
    }
}
}
```

The above awk code should work (run with awk -f codefile datafile). Essentially we are checking each line (pattern matching) for a "{" and then begin writing each line to an array (bits) until "}" is pattern matched. In addition to this an additional array (typ) is written to track lines that pattern match "Type". At the end of the code, the bits array is looped through, referencing typ. If typ contains, "NotGood", the entry in bits is ignored, otherwise it is printed.

As a one liner, the solution would be:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /{/) { strt=1;cnt++ } if (strt=1) { pnt;bits[cnt]=bits[cnt]"\n"$0;if ( $0 ~ /Type/ ) { typ[cnt]=$0 } } if ( $0 ~ /}/ ) { strt=0 } } END { for ( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { if ( typ[i] ~ /NotGood/ || typ[i] ~ /Bad/ ) { } else { printf bits[i] } } }' filename
```

Comment: How would this work for both NotGood and Bad? would that line be changed to `if ( typ[i] ~ /NotGood/ ) || ( typ[i] ~ /Bad/ )`  ? Also, if you have a chance, could you explain the syntax to me? I've never used '/' before and after the string in the above code.

Comment: Additionally, can I do it without a code file? As in put this into a variable and use that?

Comment: I've amended the solution to take account of "Bad" as well. ~ simply means pattern match against anything enclosed within the //. You can also put regular expressions within //

Comment: You can it without code and use a one liner. It would look ugly but would work.

Comment: I tried to condense it to a one-liner. It doesn't seem to work, I keep getting errors around the if statements. I'm not very fluent with awk. :(

Comment: I've added the one liner alternative to my solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147841/discussion-between-raman-sailopal-and-kip-k).